# Variable is undefined in the scope, but it's actually defined

Tags: angularjs, variables, scope, directive

I'm really confused, I don't know what heck is going on!

```
.directive("blGraph", ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      botid: "=blGraph"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      console.log(scope, scope.botid);
    }
  };
}]);
```

Result,

[image]

as you see in the picture, the **botid** exist in the **scope**, but when i try to get it by `scope.botid` it tell that it is not **defined**!

Comment: Adding this as a comment since it's not appropriate for the answer: When posting a question, even if it's implied, you should try and explicitly write what you expected, and what you got. Otherwise, you leave it to the reader to try and determine this themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a  $watch  on the scope variable. Control will go twice in the watch handler function.  You will see what is happening. 
Also what is your HTML markup, may be you are binding it to undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the sequence of running the controller and link functions, you need to use a $timeout in order to allow the variables to load onto the scope. Here's how I solved it:

```
  controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
     $timeout(function(){
        console.log($scope.myVariable)
     },0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `scope.botid` is not defined when you are printing it, and is defined after the console.log statement.

When you use console.log on an object, it shows the state of the object at the end of the JS execution.

Instead of just using scope in the console.log statement, try the following:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(scope), scope.botid);
```

Comment: We can't stringify the Scope in angularjs, it's a Circular... (`Converting circular structure to JSON`)